# swift firebase nested children dictionary delete

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nested

[firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzn11.jpg)

In the firebase structure you can see i have to delete specific user (currentUserId) in all the groups:

it's what i try to do:

```js
###########################UPDATED###################################

 let groupsRef = self.root.child("groups")
groupsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
   
    for groupChild in snapshot.children {
        let groupSnap = groupChild as! DataSnapshot
        var dict = groupSnap.value as! [String: Any]
            let uid = dict["utenti"] as! [String: Bool]
        for each in uid {                
            if each.key == self.currentUserID{
                print(each.key)
               
      //i now need a way to remove this key:value

            }
            
            }
           
        
       
    }
   
})
```

I'm new so i'm not able to go further in extracting every key of ditcionary, than i will compare to the one i have to delete and if it's the same i will delete.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          let groupsRef = self.root.child("groups")
                    groupsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                        for groupChild in snapshot.children {
                            let groupSnap = groupChild as! DataSnapshot
                            let groupKey = groupSnap.key
                            //added a groupKey to track the id of each group
                            var dict = groupSnap.value as! [String: Any]
                            var uid = dict["utenti"] as! [String: Bool]

                            //then for each key:value in uid check if is there a key = to currentuserID
                            for each in uid {

                                if each.key == self.currentUserID{
                                    uid.removeValue(forKey: each.key)
                                  //here you remove currentuserId from the dictionary and below 
                                 //finally you set back the new value of the dictionary without currentuserId

                   self.root.child("groups").child(groupKey).child("utenti").setValue(uid)

                                } 
                            }
                        }    
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
for (key, value) in uid {


}
```

to loop over a dictionary.

But really, looking in the official documentation of swift would give you the right answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
    let groupsRef = self.root.child("groups")
            groupsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                for groupChild in snapshot.children {
                    let groupSnap = groupChild as! DataSnapshot
                    for subGroupChild in groupSnap.children {
                        //Here you need to remove that specific user if condition match
                        //specificUserUID is that user's id that user to be deleted
                       if let snapref = subGroupSnap as! DatabaseReference {
                        snapref.queryOrdered(byChild: "utenti").queryEqual(toValue: specificUserUID).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

                        snapshot.removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, reference) in
                                if error != nil {
                                    print("There has been an error:\(error)")
                                 }
                         })
                        })
                       }
                    }
                }

            })
```

Your code will go like above you just need find thaat user by user ID and delete that particular snapshot.

Comment: thnx but it gives me error: "Value of type 'Any' has no member 'queryOrdered'"